# apply style to specific dates with primeng calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to apply a style to specific dates with prime ng's calendar ?

I would like to do

```
<p-calendar [datesToStyle]="arrayOfDates"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now Primeng is not providing direct array mapping as it is there for disabling specific Dates.

But I came up with a solution. I created an Array having list of dates that I wanted to highlight in the Calendar. When preparing this array I removed time part from the dates using date.setHours(0,0,0,0).

```
invalidDates: Array<Date> = new Array<Date>();
```

In the HTML having p-calendar I added an if-else condition for highlighting a date if it is present in the Array.

```
<p-calendar [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="dateFrom"  [maxDate]="dateTo" name="dateFrom" [(ngModel)]="dateFrom" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
        <div *ngIf="checkDateForHoliday(date);then highlightedDate else normalDate"></div>
        <ng-template #highlightedDate>
            <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: '#ff4d4d'}" style="border-radius:75%">{{date.day}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #normalDate>
                <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'inherit'}" style="border-radius:75%">{{date.day}}</span>
        </ng-template>

    </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

Below are the definitions of checkDateForHoliday and isInArray methods.

```
checkDateForHoliday(date:any){
    var calendarDate = new Date(date.year,date.month,date.day);
    calendarDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return this.isInArray(calendarDate);
  }

  isInArray(value:Date) {
    return !!this.invalidDates.find(item => {
      return item.getTime() == value.getTime()});
  }
```

Make sure that the Date Array you are preparing(invalidDates in my case) should not have time part. Use setHours method as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Date Template  in the calendar documentation

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h3>Date Template</h3>
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date10">
        <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
            <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day < 21 && date.day > 10) ? '#7cc67c' : 'inherit'}" style="border-radius:50%">{{date.day}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach is recommended!

Comment: The problem I run into with this solution is, the `<span>` that is added cannot be made bigger because it is constricted by the parent's padding. So the highlight is all small and thus not fully customizable.

Comment: Eva - to fix the height you just need to do a little more with styling since you are talking about something outside of the scope of the question.  You can add or remove styling, turn it into a div, add a class, use ng deep. What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

No as of now there no such attribute for styling specific dates

see here for list of attributes supported

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

PS: Added new feature of Disabling specific Dates.

Also you can change in the library if needed.